# Add Favicon to Hexo Blog

Tags: node.js, hexo

I have made a Hexo blog. I can't however find out where to add the favicon. I have tried adding it to different folders but it isn't being found.

Does anyone know where it should be added or if there is anything else I need to update.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on theme you're using, check theme documentation and source.

Some themes, like [apollo](https://github.com/joyceim/hexo-theme-apollo) are supports `favicon` config parameter (`theme_config.favicon` parameter in_config.yml).

If theme does not support a custom favicon, then just add file `source/favicon.ico` and it will be [requested by browser automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use).

Answer (score 2):

I use Landscape, the default theme at time of writing.

```
blog\blog\node_modules\hexo\node_modules\hexo-cli\assets\themes\landscape\_config.yml
```

At the bottom of the file, you'll find a section titled Miscellaneous.

```
# Miscellaneous 
google_analytics:
favicon: blog\themes\landscape\source\css\images\favicon.ico
twitter:
google_plus:
fb_admins:
fb_app_id:
```

Windows can be directionally-challenged when it comes to slashes, so try the opposite direction if you use PC. This took some fudging on my part, and I was able to use an .ico file as well as a .png.

If you're still in need of a placeholder image, I've used [Favicon.cc](http://www.favicon.cc/) and had great results.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the `favicon.ico` in the source floder, and add a line in the `blog/_config.yml`

```
favicon: favicon.ico
```

so, you know the `source` is the root path

Answer (score 1):

I think all the other answers are so confused.
Now just three steps to add a **favicon** to your **hexo-blog website**, and I take `next` theme as example:

- First, download your favorite `imagename.ico` image file from network or you make one by yourself.
- Second, rename the `imagename.ico` file to `favicon.ico`, then move it to that folder: `blog/themes/next(the theme folder you are using now)/source/images/`.
- Finally, modify the code in file `blog/themes/next/_config.yml` at that line to the same as below:

  > ```
  > # Put your favicon.ico into `hexo-site/source/` directory.
  > favicon: images/favicon.ico
  > ```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Konstantin Pavlov is right.
for example, I use hexo-theme-next theme.
I change code in themes/next/_config.yml.

```
# Put your favicon.ico into `hexo-site/source/` directory.
favicon: images/favicon.ico
```

I put my favicon.ico in themes/next/source/images/favicon.ico
well Done.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the head part of the html code...

```
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.w3.org/Icons/w3c_home">
  </head>
```

For more on this have a look at the W3C site : [How To FavIcon](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

It's also good to inspect the page source by looking at the console as it will report if there were any issue retrieving the icon.

Comment: This answer, while pointing to a related favicon resource does not answer the question related to Hexo site generator.